# jquery media not show player

Tags: theming, javascript, files

I'm trying to use [jQuery Media](http://drupal.org/project/jquery_media), but it's not working.
I am getting the following error in Firebug:

> "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://
>   demo.dolphin-sch.ir/nagara/fa/sites/default/files/mediaplayer/player.swf?file=http://demo.dolphin-sch.ir/nagara/sites/default/files/audio/12.mp3"

You can see the error on my website:

> http://demo.dolphin-sch.ir/nagara/fa/content/abc

First I enable jQuery Media (version 6.x-1.4-beta1) and [jQ](http://drupal.org/project/jq) (version 6.x-1.2) and then upload the [JW FLV Player](http://%20www.longtailvideo.com/players/jw-flv-player/) to `sites/default/files/mediaplayer/player.swf`.  Next I change my `template.php` and create a `filefield_file.tpl.php` file.  Lastly, I set a media class `.field-field-flash-file a, .filefield-file-audio a` but it's still not working.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two locations specified for `sites/default/files` are different in your example:

First part: http://demo.dolphin-sch.ir/nagara/fa/sites/default/files/mediaplayer/player.swf?file=

Second part:  http://demo.dolphin-sch.ir/nagara/sites/default/files/audio/12.mp3

I'd check your paths are set correctly everywhere.

**EDIT:**

This link works fine:

http://demo.dolphin-sch.ir/nagara/sites/default/files/mediaplayer/player.swf?file=http://demo.dolphin-sch.ir/nagara/sites/default/files/audio/12.mp3

Comment: thanks a lot How can setting height mp3 file and video file